# Phone Gap Application Store in App store 'INVALID BINARY' in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, ios-universal-app

I have created a phoneGap app for universal and successfully deployed it device.

Now i am trying to upload the app to app store using xcode 4.4

Successfully validated.

Successfully Distributed.

itunes connect app status-- app received

after 3sec app status-- invalid binary

I have not received any e mail followup from apple

I am using phone gap 2.3.0, xcode 4.4, target ios version 4.3, Distribution provisional profile.

Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using phone gap 2.3.0, xcode 4.4, target ios version 4.3, Distribution provisional profile.

I don't know what the minimum acceptable SDK is right now, but Xcode 4.4 is pretty old. You should consider switching up to the current version.

Also, certain methods in the API are deprecated, and using them may prevent your app from being accepted. For example, the `-[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` method won't be acceptable starting May 1, 2013. At the same time, there are certain requirements that your app has to meet -- all iPhone apps have to be able to run on an iPad, for example, and I think any new apps are also expected to work with the iPhone 5's screen dimensions. I'm not sure that these reasons would cause a 3 second delay, but you should make sure that you're aware of the current requirements and stick to them.